# Use `$expr` in update query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How to use `$expr` in mongoose and MongoDB query

When I try with `findAndModify`

```
const createConversation = await Conversations.findAndModify({
  query: {
    type: 'P', members: { $in: payload.members },
    $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$members" }, 1 ] }
  },
  update: { $set: payload },
  upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true
})
```

The above gives me an error which is obvious as it is a MongoDB function, not a mongoose

`TypeError: _conversationsModel2.default.findAndModify is not a function`

and when I try with `findOneAndUpdate`

```
const createConversation = await Conversations.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    type: 'P', members: { $in: payload.members },
    $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$members" }, 1 ] }
  },
  { $set: payload },
  { upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, strict: false }
)
```

It gives me

```
"name": "MongoError",
"message": "$expr is not allowed in the query predicate for an upsert"
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!!!

Comment: the message clearly says that when using option upsert true, you cant use $expr

Comment: try without upsert

Comment: yes it works but I want to upsert the data...

Comment: Does it possible in findAndModify mongdb method with $expr

Comment: yes have a look https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/03/09/mongodb-3-6-using-the-new-expression-query-operator-expr/

Comment: In the link example they used $expr but they didnt used upsert: true option, so I think it is not possible with upsert true

Comment: Ok lets see if any one has some other way to do it or knows the answer